# Gridview using a generic list as DataSource and Auto-generating columns

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, gridview

I'm looking to load a GridView with a generic list and have the columns be auto-generated. I am getting an exception that it does not have the correct properties to allow it to auto-generate the columns.

**Exception**

```
The data source for GridView with id 'GV1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.
```

**GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

**Page Load**

```
    //LINQ query to populate list
    List<student> su = new List<student>();
    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();
    var q = from c in db.data_table
            where c.processed == false
            orderby c.date_complete descending
            select c;
     //iterate through results and add to list
     foreach(var c in q)
     {
         student s = new student { name = c.name, address = c.address };
         su.Add(s);
     } 

     //Load GridView
     GV1.DataSource = su;
     GV1.DataBind(); //Exception thrown here
```

**Student Class**

```
public class student
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated, feel free to let me know if I'm going about this completely wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try adjusting your `student` class and change your fields into properties like this:

```
public class student
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This answered a similar question that I had. What I don't understand is why it works. Why is it that I can access `student.name` manually but `GridView` can't do it unless I add the accessors?

Comment: I can't say specifically, I can only tell you that the grid will only access properties and not fields.  I can *guess* that when it does the reflection, it reflects onto public properties (`BindingFlags.GetProperty`) and not public fields (`BindingFlags.GetField`).

Comment: After hours of searching, you are a god send. This answer solved my problem. Thank you!