# Display Data from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

How can i show Data from a class into a gridview?
MY Class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class EmployeeDetails
{
    private int employeeID;

    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeID = value;
        }
    }

    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }

    private string lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
        }
    }

    private string titleOfCourtesy;

    public string TitleOfCourtesy
    {
        get
        {
            return titleOfCourtesy;
        }
        set
        {
            titleOfCourtesy = value;
        }
    }

    public EmployeeDetails(int employeeID, string firstName, string lastName, string titleOfCourtesy)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        TitleOfCourtesy = titleOfCourtesy;
    }
}
```

I`ve done this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 15;
        string f_name = "asd";
        string l_name = "asd";
        string title = "asd";

        EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails(id,f_name,l_name,title);

        emp.EmployeeID = id;
        emp.FirstName = f_name;
        emp.LastName = l_name;
        emp.TitleOfCourtesy = title;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159287/gridview-using-a-generic-list-as-datasource-and-auto-generating-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GridView` is generally used to display multiple objects/rows. To get it to display your class you need to make a collection containing your class, such as a `List<EmployeeDetails>`. Then bind that to your gridview.

You could use another control more suited to displaying a single object such as a `DetailsView`.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<EmployeeDetails> lst = new List<EmployeeDetails>() ;
GridView1.DataSource = lst ;
GrdiView1.DataBind();
```

you may populate the list with your `EmployeeDetails` Objects

Comment: datasource is an invalid type.

Comment: @Abid: how it come to be invalid? what do you mean?

Comment: before your edited your answer it was **<gridview1.datasource = emp;>**

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for an answer to show multiple item instead of just 1.

C#

```
var myList = List<EmploymentDetails>();

foreach (var employee in SomeOtherDataSource)
{
    EmployeeDetails emp =  new EmployeeDetails{EmployeeID = id, FirstName = f_name, LastName = l_name, TitleOfCourtesy = title};
    myList.Add(emp);
}

var EmployeeDS = from eds in myList select new { ID = EmployeeID, FName = FirstName, LName = LastName, Title = TitleofCourtest };

MyGridview.DataSource = EmployeeDS;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

By doing this: `var EmployeeDS = from eds in myList select new { ID = EmployeeID, FName = FirstName, LName = LastName, Title = TitleofCourtest };` it makes it possible to just use `<%# Eval('ID/FName/LName/Title'%>` in the GridView's boundfields instead of those long variable names you've made in your entity class.