# ASP.Net Datagridview paging without using SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, list, entity, paging

I'm working on one project where data is coming from the WCF web services and in the List format.

Firstly, Is it possible to assign that list directly to the data grid view? If not then I'm converting that list into Dataset and binding to the Grid but the problem is, Collection List contains thousand of records and converting into Dataset decrease the performance.

Also, This is a direct bing with List or the Dataset to Gridview so is it possible to achieve the paging including First, Previous, Next, Last and Page sets?

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can 'directly' do it but somehow , theres a way. Here is a question of the same matter.
[Gridview using a generic list as DataSource and Auto-generating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159287/gridview-using-a-generic-list-as-datasource-and-auto-generating-columns)

Comment: Above example is good for binding the List<Entity> to Datagridview but can we implement paging from collection only?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand, you want to page the collection alone?

Comment: You want to page it on runtime?

Comment: Yes need a paging on Datagridview that interact with the List<Entity> and get the page wise records from the List<Entity>.